# useRTDB Issue: Cannot access database variable using .value

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, ref

I am working with a vue.js composition application and firebase and have the following snippet of code:

```
<script setup>
import { useRTDB } from '@vueuse/firebase/useRTDB'

const dbMembers = useRTDB(db.ref('members'))
console.log('dbMembers', dbMembers, dbMembers.value)
</script>
```

dbMembers loads in as a ref in console, which contains the object I am looking for. However, when I try to access this object or do any operations on it using dbMembers.value, I get undefined. I'm not quite sure how the mechanics of useRTDB work, but any help is appreciated!